# Issue Pickling Dataflow Pipeline on Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am running a pipeline that follows a general format as such:

```
def dataflow_job_run(files_list, bucket):
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.io import ReadAllFromText
    from apache_beam.io import filesystems
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    from <custom_module> import func1

    class SpecialOutputClass(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element):
            path = bucket+element[0]
            writer = filesystems.FileSystems.create(f'{path}')
            writer.write(bytes(element[1], 'utf-8')
            writer.close()

    dataflow_options = <dataflow_options_list>
    options = PipelineOptions(dataflow_options)

    transform  = (p | beam.Create(files_list) | ReadAllFromText(with_filename=True) | beam.Map(func1) | beam.GroupByKey() | beam.ParDo(SpecialOutputClass()))

    result = p.run()
```

This code works perfectly when I run it locally, but when I try to run this in Airflow(v1.10), I run into an error.. I cut the pipeline into separate components, and the one that causes the issue s the last ParDo:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/dill_pickler.py", line 285, in loads
return dill.loads(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 275, in loads
return load(file, ignore, **kwds)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 270, in load
return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load
obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 826, in _import_module
return __import__(import_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unusual_prefix_*'
```

Where the '*' just represents the name of the dag. Based on the error message, it seems like the problem might be the way that DAGs are pickled in Airflow.. and for some reason, it just doesn't pickle the ParDo class properly... is there a way to go around this problem?

**EDIT**: If I change the SpecialOutputClass into a function and run `beam.Map()` it'll work.. so clearly there is something going on with the `ParDo()` aspect. While this clears up some of the problem, I am curious how to allow the original code to work. Some additional considerations, I do not have `donot_pickle = True` and I am running on a `CeleryExecutor`.

Comment: When you indicate it works locally, you mean with "directRunner" or "dataflowRunner" ?

Comment: Hi Mazlum. This works with Dataflow Runner.. I usually develop locally to test out Dataflow and then switch to Composer whenever it works

Comment: Hi Aaron. The Apache Beam version used locally is it the same as the Apache Beam version used by Cloud Composer/Airflow ?

Comment: Hi Mazlum, that is a good point. Do you know how I can check that information in Composer?

Comment: You can check it from the cloud composer version in the following link, PyPackages are shown for each Composer version : https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions

Comment: Hi Mazlum. Yes. The version for apache-beam is equal for local and Composer environment. Just checked now.

Comment: I found this link : https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/208  I am not sure but I have the feeling that your problem is due to the usage of ˋfilesList` in your code.

Comment: Since you run your pipeline on dataflow, Why wouldn't you create a flex template for it, and then run the  pipeline using the `DataflowStartFlexTemplateOperator` operator from the composer?

Comment: @AaronGonzalez can you tell me what this job doing and what your trying to achive

Comment: @chethi Thanks for reaching out. This job receives x number of files and performs a transformation on each file. We want the number of output files to match the input files, so for example x1 -> x1_transformed, etc. As mentioned in the description.. The problem is not the pipeline itself.. but rather an issue with Composer and beam.ParDo().